# How to scrape all comments section using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape all the comments from this website it has load more button to get more comments i want to get them all.

This is the site: [link here](https://www.rok.guide/buildings/lyceum-of-wisdom/)

I tried with this code but nothing worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def scrape_comments(url):
    # Set up Chrome driver options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--block-notifications")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    # Set up Selenium web driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Open the website
    driver.get(url)

    # Find the "Load More Comments" button
    load_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpd-load-more-submit')))

    # Click the "Load More Comments" button until all comments are loaded
    while load_more_button.is_displayed():
        load_more_button.click()
        load_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpd-load-more-submit')))

    # Extract the comments
    comments = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wpd-comment-content')

    # Close the web driver
    driver.quit()

    return [comment.text for comment in comments]
```